# Informatica mapping creation from sql query

Tags: sql, mapping, transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to create mapping where I need to check if any duplicates. I have below sql query from which I have to create the mapping.

```
Select count(1), A.market_cd
from (select distinct account_no, market_cd
   from Db1.Table1
   where $$monthenddate between date(eff_begin) and 
        date(eff_end) 
   group by account_no, market_cd having count(1) > 1
) A 
group by market_cd ;

Select count(1), A.market_cd
from (select distinct account_no, market_cd
   from Db2.Table2
   where $$monthenddate between date(eff_begin) and 
        date(eff_end) 
   group by account_no, market_cd having count(1) > 1
) A 
group by market_cd ;

Select count(1), A.market_cd
from (select distinct account_no, market_cd 
   from Db3.Table3
   where $$monthenddate between date(eff_begin) and 
        date(eff_end) 
   group by account_no, market_cd having count(1) > 1
) A 
group by market_cd
```

Result:-

```
Count | Market_cd
0
```

Ideal result for the above queries should be zero rows. I have to check if the result gives any count or not.

I have to Union all the above queries in target flat file.
What logic and transformation can be used to create the mapping?
Please can someone help

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "2 different tables".  You should ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: I have 3 tables from 3 different databases from which I have to get the combined result in target flatfile. Please check edited question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... you can use `count (distinct account_no)` and get rid of subqueries. [More info here.](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-distinct.php)

Next, create a mapping in Informatica with three sources and `Source qualifiers` - and same way as in the query - add `Aggregator` for each one and use `Union` to combine the results.

On each `Source Qualifier` use the `Source Filter` property to limit the amount of rows according to your needs by putting: `$$monthenddate between date(eff_begin) and date(eff_end)`.

Remember to add the mapping variable and set it's value, best by a paramter file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes I have used the similar transformations.  also have used expression trans for the date condition in where clause. I have one question like in aggregate trans I can give the count()>1 condition in the expression tab of aggregate transformation rt?

Comment: Also can you give some insights on the variable $$monthenddate part. How can I implement the where condition logic. Can we write the where condition in SQL override in source qualifier? Will that work?